# javascript how to find an error in a script

Tags: javascript, firebug, custom-error-handling

I know this is a little to less to get an answer on what the problem is so what I ask is how to debug it.

I get the following error (the image below). No line, script or anything specified. Also except the ones in jQuery and raphaeljs libraries I don't have any custom error handler defined.

[image]

Got any ideas on how to debug this?

(The main script for example has around 3k lines and since I don't know where the error occurs I don't know witch part of it to post. I need only a way to find that.)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: errors like that usually mean that you messed sth up with your code that uses these libraries (i.e. you forgot to add coma, close the parenthesis, ...) - check your code, line through line

Comment: nice option but there are lots and when I say lots I mean lots of scripts there... I can't just paste everything :). @matt

Comment: I agree on using JSLint, but the reason why is because it'll clean up your code in a way that should make wrong code look wrong. It will also help catch nasty little syntax errors.

Comment: @h4: Usually if I get a syntax error I get the line in firebug... (exception at warnings)... this time I got nothing. Also the script doesn't break.

Comment: why can't you use JSLint? don't get lazy just because it's a large script. sometimes you just have to dive in and get dirty.

Comment: 87 files. That are loaded dynamically in corelation with what users selects... that would be the main reason. I'm not lazy... or at least not that lazy... but that would be criminal. :P

Comment: well... I have a feeling something's seriously wrong if you have to load 87 different js scripts.

Comment: Not if it is a damn game. Can we please stay on topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when the script throws a string, rather than a proper exception, like:

```
throw 'Error in protected function: )55';
```

See this other SO question for possible solutions:

[How can I get a Javascript stack trace when I throw an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591857/how-can-i-get-a-javascript-stack-trace-when-i-throw-an-exception)

Answer (score 0):

Try chrome. Webkit can provide stack traces:
[Web Inspector: Understanding Stack Traces](http://www.webkit.org/blog/1544/web-inspector-understanding-stack-traces/)

Sample:

```
<script>
    function i2(){
        throw "CustomError";
    }
    function invoke(){
        i2();
    }

</script>
<button onclick="invoke()">yo</button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

local function ensureAnimDict(animDict)
if not HasAnimDictLoaded(animDict) then
RequestAnimDict(animDict)
while not HasAnimDictLoaded(animDict) do
Wait(0)
end
return animDict
end

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).