# printing line numbers

Tags: javascript, numbers, line

For debugging, I want to be able to print messages, and have the line number prepended.
No, I don't want to get involved with a full-fledged debugger.

I have defined a global constant `ln="thisline = new Error().lineNumber";`

I have defined a

```
function println(msg) { 
    document.write("<br>at " + thisline + ":" + msg);
}
```

Then at the lines I want to debug I put a line saying:

```
eval(ln);
println("msg");
```

The problem is that `thisline` often doesn't get updated before the print, so I get long stretches with an unchanging line number. I never get more than 3 unique line numbers printed.

Is it just that the eval is too slow? Is there some way to wait till it finishes?
I tried a timeout:

```
const ln="setTimeout(function() { 
    thisline = new Error().lineNumber
}, 1000);"
```

but the global `thisline` never got set.

Or is it that there is some system limit on the number of errors I can raise?

Comment: Are you aware [there already is a console in your browser](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) and that `console.log` outputs the line number (and the whole stack) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the application in IE, then press F12 key(Developer tools) and another popup will open.

click on the Script Tab and click on Start Debugging button.

the page will refresh and you can start performing actions.

on any error, the debugger will automatically take you to the error line number. you can also place break points.

else you can look at the below following post:

[How can I get a Javascript stack trace when I throw an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591857/how-can-i-get-a-javascript-stack-trace-when-i-throw-an-exception)