# Dependency tracking modules from a concatenated library

Tags: javascript, dependencies, source-maps

#### What I've got

A large (proprietary unfortunately) JS library, the many small modules that get rolled up into it during the build process, the accompanying source map, and over 300 examples that use the built version of the library.

#### The goal

A form of dependency tracking, I guess? I need to be able to modify one of the small modules, rebuild the large file, and then only re-verify the examples that were affected by this change. **Note**: I don't care whether this requires static analysis or if I have to run all examples thru a headless browser to extract something or so - I'm fine as long as it can be automated.

#### What I've tried so far

I've read answers to questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445761/get-a-list-of-all-functions-that-are-called-by-another-function) and tried pre-existing tools like 
[Madge](https://github.com/pahen/madge), but none of them seem to work for my case. Madge in particular is great for telling me which of the modules depend on which modules, but that's not what I'm looking for. Most solutions online are based on the assumption that you're already using something like `require.js` or similar on which they can piggy-back, but in my case the library is simply just a giant blob.
My current approach is instrumenting the built version of the library by simply appending every line with something like `neededModules["the_file_this_line_comes_from.module.js"] = true` similar to how code coverage tools do it. However, that fails because of several parts like this:

```
Points.prototype = Object.assign( Object.create( Info.prototype ), {

    plot: ( function () {
        var static = new Background();

        return function plot( line, physics ) {
            <code>
        };
    }() ),

    copy: function () {
        return new this.constructor( this.info, this.history ).copy( this );
    }
} );
```

The `copy` function is tracked/skipped just fine, but because the `plot` function is an IIFE(right?), the line `var static = new Background();` always gets executed, even if there is absolutely no connection to the `Points` module.

#### What I'm looking for

Either some help with my current approach and its problems with IIFE or a different solution altogether. I've seen Facebook's [Jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest) does offer dependency tracking, maybe someone has experience with that one, or there's some way to incorporate the source map?
Again, as long as it's automatable and finishes in let's say < 5 min, I'm totally fine with it no matter if it's static analysis or just some hacky script or whatever :)

Thanks!