# How to find which controller caused exception in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to handle my Application errors by extending `$exceptionHandler`, with respect to that I registered a provider like below:

```
app.provider("$exceptionHandler", function() {
    return function(exception, cause) {
        // here I want to get the Controller which thrown the error
    }
});
```

Is there a way we can find it out?

Update:

In general I want to show a custom error message only for a section (particular scope in my `html`) which throws an exception. Is there a better way to handle this case generically

For e.g. `"Data Unavailable"` or `"Unknown Error occurred"`

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591857/how-can-i-get-a-javascript-stack-trace-when-i-throw-an-exception