# How can I get a JavaScript stack trace of an error in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, runtime-error, stack-trace

I've searched all other questions and they tell me to use `.trace()`

However when a minified library throws an error, I don't have an option to add a `.trace()`

In Node.js when you get an error it shows a stack trace automatically.

Is there no such option to view the stack trace in firefox?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591857/how-can-i-get-a-javascript-stack-trace-when-i-throw-an-exception.  Also, develop in Chrome.

Comment: Many people already answered it, did you Google it once. First result says -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591857/how-can-i-get-a-javascript-stack-trace-when-i-throw-an-exception did you try this out

Comment: @MikeHometchko I acknowledged that in my question that I've read that question. I can't call `.trace()`

Comment: @laggingreflex so you're saying that for some reason you can't breakpoint your code and review the stack trace through firebug/chrome dev console?  If you are using a minified version of a script on production then well done.  Why wouldn't you be using the unminified version for debugging?  That's what it's for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox has a built in debugger, accessible by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>. Now would be a good time to [read the instructions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger). Seeing as you're using minified Javascript, the `Auto Prettify Minified Sources` option might come in handy. Usually it's better to use the full-fat Javascript source code until deployment.

Comment: Does it only show the stack trace when you manually put stop-markers? It's showing empty otherwise for my error.

Comment: @laggingreflex: That would be one way... Place a break-point on the line that causes the error... If you install Firebug, it has a "break on error" feature that breaks execution the moment an error occurs, allowing you to look at the callstack at the moment the error occurred. There might be a similar option in the on-board debugger. It certainly seems quite advanced compared to the last time I looked.

Comment: Ah yes, there is a Pause on exception.