# Error().stack undefined in Cordova iOS, but works on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

The following javascript code prints "stack is undefined" on iOS 6.1 / Xcode 5 using Cordova 3.4, but it works fine (prints nothing) using Cordova on Android. It also works fine in a web browser. What's so different about iOS?

```
if (typeof new Error().stack == 'undefined') {
    console.log("stack is undefined.");
}
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [Error.stack is a non-standard property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/stack) and may not be present in all browsers. It appears they did not write it into Cordova on iOS.

Comment: So sad. Is it possible to get the stack trace another way?

Comment: It's quite hacky but [there is a way to get it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/635852/371184) without the `Error.stack` property.