# Finding Out the Invoked Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am debugging a third party JS file. When I click on a certain link it displays a menu. I want to find out what function in the third party js is called to display the menu? The HTML is not using inline functions?

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591857/how-can-i-get-a-javascript-stack-trace-when-i-throw-an-exception

Comment: JS Beautifier the JS file if it's minified and then `CTRL+F` click/onclick?