# Javascript get amount of functions on the Call Stack

Tags: javascript

I am trying to read the amount of functions on the call stack. 
Is there any possibility to do this with javascript?

Thank you in advance!

**edit:** As far as I understand, the call stack contains the functions which are excecuted at the moment. For example

```
foo(){
bar();
}
```

leads to the call stack

```
bar
foo
```

My question is now if it is possible to get the amount of functions (in this case 2)

Comment: If you could describe the problem you're trying to solve, it might help people make useful suggestions.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/591857/327815) close to what you are after?

Comment: i edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question lacks detail so I assume the following specs: *output a count of the number of functions in a stack trace*.

First get the stack trace by constructing an error.

```
function getStack() {
  return new Error().stack;
}
```

Each call in the stack trace is separated by a new line so we can count them:

```
function getStackCount() {
  return new Error().stack.split('\n').length;
}
```

To adjust for the function call here you could minus two (one for the `new Error()` and one for the `getStackCount()`:

```
function getStackCount() {
  return Math.max(new Error().stack.split('\n').length - 2, 0);
}
```