# get filename from a stacktrace

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, filenames

I have a failing unit test and i am writing a custom jasmine reporter that would requires me to get the name of the file from the stack trace provided by it.

`Verify the most recent consumer review is showing all information. (0.683 sec)
        - Expected true to be false, 'test title'.
            at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xyz/Documents/tests/somefolder/xyz.test.js:25:72)
            at /Users/xyz/Documents/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:96:23
            at new Promise (/Users/xyz/Documentsc/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1043:7.....`

What is the best way just to get the name of the file `xyz.test.js` from above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a Javascript stack trace when I throw an exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591857/how-can-i-get-a-javascript-stack-trace-when-i-throw-an-exception)

Answer (score 1):

If the traceback is stored in a string, and you want to extract the filename using regex (may not work for all types of exceptions):

```js
var traceback = "Verify the most recent consumer review is showing all information. (0.683 sec) \
        - Expected true to be false, 'test title'. \
            at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xyz/Documents/tests/somefolder/xyz.test.js:25:72) \
            at /Users/xyz/Documents/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:96:23 \
            at new Promise (/Users/xyz/Documentsc/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1043:7....."
            
console.log(/\(.*\/([^\/]*.js).*\)/.exec(traceback)[1])
```

```
\(.*/([^/]*.js).*\)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/m0O9m5snP8uLhjGG)

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use a regexp for this, but if you want a bit more functionality, [`stacktrace-parser`](https://github.com/errwischt/stacktrace-parser) is useful:

```
const parse = require('stacktrace-parser').parse;
const path  = require('path');

let trace = `
        - Expected true to be false, 'test title'.
            at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xyz/Documents/tests/somefolder/xyz.test.js:25:72)
            at /Users/xyz/Documents/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:96:23
            at new Promise (/Users/xyz/Documentsc/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1043:7
`;

console.log( path.basename( parse(trace)[0].file ) )
// outputs: xyz.test.js
```