# How to make something happen only if no errors were found?

Tags: javascript

I know I can detect an error like this..

```
img.onerror = function() {
    console.log('error');
}
```

But is there a way to make something happen only if no errors were found?

EDIT: specifically I'm trying to link an img from a different source

```
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'link';
```

is there a way to detect if the link is found then append it to body ONLY if it's found?

Comment: "is there a way to make something happen only if no errors were found?" - found where ?

Comment: when linking an image. I'll edit the question to be more specific

Comment: [This question might be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591857/how-can-i-get-a-javascript-stack-trace-when-i-throw-an-exception).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to confirm that the image exist first before loading it to the body, you could do something like this with jquery

```
var image_url = "https://www.google.co.nz/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" ;

$('<img src="'+ image_url +'">').load(function() {
  alert("image found")
  $(this).appendTo('#testDivID');
}).fail(function() { 
    alert("image not found")
});;
```

Here is a JS fiddle URL: https://jsfiddle.net/cmd939p4/

Comment: Updated the answer to only show the image if it is found. I also supplied a jsfiddle example.