# Profiling async functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, promise, async-await, profiling

I have a complex flow of async/await functions that I would like to optimise.

Using the built-in profiler of Chrome dev tools is practical when debugging synchronous workflows, but tracking micro-tasks triggers to resume promises is a difficult workflow and gives little overview.

Different ideas: I was thinking in the lines of exploiting babel-generated code to gather time spent in different stages of promise resolving, or perhaps using untranspiled code and overriding the global `Promise` object to gain performance insights.

How can I debug performance of async/await functions in an effective manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After not getting any responses here, I made my own solution. It's very rough, but working. I did this by overriding the global Promise object. This only works for babel-transpiled async functions since native async apparently didn't respect the overridden window.promise. Through stack inspection by using `Error().stack` (thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591857/how-can-i-get-a-javascript-stack-trace-when-i-throw-an-exception)) I could determine who was creating that promise.

The result can be found [here](https://github.com/Karolusrex/promise-performance) and you can use `npm i promise-performance`