# How to get the object reference from caller in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arguments

I implemented a small (and probably not standard) function to get the call stack in JavaScript. However, this piece of code below only gets the function references. Is it possible the object to every caller?

```
function getCallStack() {
  let stack = [];
  let caller = arguments.callee.caller;

  while (caller !== null) {
   stack.push(caller); // I would like "stack.push([caller, getObject(caller)]);
   caller = caller.caller; 
  }
  return stack;
}
```

If I execute the following piece of code `console.log(getCallStack())`, I can get something like `[ [Function: f3], [Function: f2], [Function: f1] ]`. I would like to get something like [ `[[Function: f3], obj3], [[Function: f2], obj2], [[Function: f1], obj1] ]` where `obj1, obj2, obj3` are JUST references to the objects.

Comment: References to *what* objects?

Comment: I believe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591857/how-can-i-get-a-javascript-stack-trace-when-i-throw-an-exception

Comment: @Pointy, object of each caller, eg. `obj1.f1();`, I want `obj1`

Comment: You can't access that, I don't think. What you're asking for is how `this` is bound in each parent function, and that's not exposed. If you check that answer linked in another comment you'll see that there are more modern ways of getting stack traces.

Comment: @mamounothman , console.trace only returns these values as a string, but I require their references.

Comment: @Pointy thanks, but I require to analyze the trace to make some decisions, for example, execute some function if the trace contains the `obj1` executing the method `f1`.

Comment: What I'm saying is that JavaScript, via `arguments` or anything else, does not provide access to that information. Things like the debugger and `console.trace()` can "cheat" because they have access to the runtime via non-JavaScript APIs.

Comment: @NaiveDeveloper there are other technique in that issue that can be used to trace back the whole stack, e.g answer by user2223787 or maybe you will need a whole framework around your codebase to trace everything, e.g https://www.stacktracejs.com/