# How can I find the calling function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebug, dom-events

I have a function in JS which is getting called from multiple places..

Now I am testing this page on an iPad and hence find debugging a bit hard.

Can I find out by some way (print on console) from where my function is getting called from ?

Comment: This will help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript

Comment: One more link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147891/javascript-exception-stack-trace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you find out the caller function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Like this?

```
function testOne() {
    console.log("Test 1");
    logTest();
}
function testTwo() {
    console.log("Test 2");
    logTest();
}
function logTest() {
    console.log("Being called from " + arguments.callee.caller.toString());
}

testOne();
testTwo();
```

If you use `'use strict';` in your JavaScript file, you need to comment/remove it, because otherwise you'll get something like this:

> Uncaught TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them

Comment: I am getting an error....Result of expression arguments.callee.caller is not an object

Answer (score 14):

A simple way I like to use is `arguments.callee.caller.name`.

Say you wanted to know what was calling a function called myFunction:

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log(arguments.callee.caller.name);
    /* Other stuff... */
}
```

The browser support for this isn't that great, though, so you could use arguments.callee.caller.toString() instead. Note that this will give you back the contents of the function that called myFunction, so you will need to dig out the function name from that yourself.

Or, you could use a nice stack trace function like this:

```
function getStack(){
    fnRE  = /function\s*([\w\-$]+)?\s*\(/i;
    var caller = arguments.callee.caller;
    var stack = "Stack = ";
    var fn;
    while (caller){
        fn = fnRE.test(caller.toString()) ? RegExp.$1 || "{?}" : "{?}";
        stack += "-->"+fn;
        caller = caller.arguments.callee.caller;
    };
    return stack;
}
```

Stack Trace via http://www.amirharel.com/2010/01/25/using-caller-and-callee-for-stack-trace/

Answer (score 3):

Do not use *function*.caller it is [non standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) and is not recommended.

Instead use the browser console and put break points on your function check the call stack, Here is a screenshot of chrome debugger console

[image]

Comment: if you are not running javascript in a browser (in nodejs for example) use stack trace https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Call_stack

Answer (score 2):

**Want to Detail about caller Function:**

```
function nishant(){  // Caller function 
   kumar();
}nishant();

function kumar(){ // Callee
 console.log("This functiona is being called by " + arguments.callee.caller.toString());
}
```

In place of `arguments.callee.caller.toString()` we can also use `functionName.caller`

**Example:**

```
function nishant(){  // Caller function 
   kumar();
}nishant();

function kumar(){ // Callee
 console.log("This functiona is being called by " + kumar.caller);
}
```

Output: will be same in both of the above case

```
This functiona is being called by function nishant()
{
kumar();
}
```

Comment: *functionName.caller* is a nice one, but [non standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) (according to MDN)