# Angular custom error handler not getting error type from promise

Tags: angular, error-handling, promise, rxjs, custom-error-handling

When thrown from a promise every Error my custom error handler is getting does loose its type

```js
import { HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector, NgZone } from "@angular/core";
import { MatSnackBar } from "@angular/material";

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

    handleError(error: any): void {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) // this needs to be triggered
            this.injector.get(NgZone).run(() => this.injector.get(MatSnackBar).open(error.message))

        console.error(error)
    }

}
```

findProject(2) will throw a HttpErrorResponse since project 2 does not exist.

Working

```js
this.projectService.findProject(2).subscribe()
```

Not working

```
await this.projectService.findProject(2).toPromise()
```

Not working

```js
await this.projectService.findProject(2).toPromise().catch(error => { throw error })
```

Not working

```js
try {
  await this.projectService.findProject(2).toPromise()
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e instanceof HttpErrorResponse) // true
  throw e
}
```

ProjectService is a swagger generated class which returns an Observable

Edit:
This is the error object in handleError method:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":404,"statusText":"OK","url":"http://localhost:9090/api/project/2","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://localhost:9090/api/project/2: 404 OK","error":{"timestamp":1534921795114,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","exception":"de.dlh.lhind.lhindquiz.controller.ResourceNotFoundException","message":"No message available","path":"/api/project/2"}}
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at zone.js:724
    at rejected (main.js:105)
    at ...
```

It seems like the promise wraps the HttpErrorResponse around a regular Error and error.message is indeed the requested object

Comment: Without going into the if statement, log out 'error', what does it say it's type is?

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: Have a very similar issue. Within a promise stream it won't work, but will work with a subscription stream.

Answer (score 23):

I just hit the same issue and stumbled upon your question.

Seems you can fix this (at least in Angular 7) by unwrapping the exception in your ErrorHandler if needed.

```
if (error.promise && error.rejection) {
    // Promise rejection wrapped by zone.js
    error = error.rejection;
}

// regular error handling code
```

Note: I figured out the structure of the wrapping Error object using `console.error("%O", error)` as per this question: [Chrome: Print exception details to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036121/chrome-print-exception-details-to-console)

Comment: Thanks got the same issue in an Ionic Angular Cordova app, specially in iOS app. This line solves the issue. All errors thrown from an **unawaited** async method, Angular Error Handler catches them and returns them as a Promise.

Comment: When doing it like this, the error message sent by server in `{ error: { message: "could not read results from json files" } }` ends up like this: `error: "{\"message\":\"could not read results from json files\"}\n"`

Answer (score 0):

You can "Disable wrapping uncaught promise rejection" by setting `DISABLE_WRAPPING_UNCAUGHT_PROMISE_REJECTION`. Follow the [Angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/zone#setting-up-zonejs) and see the [configuration](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/zone.js/lib/zone.configurations.api.ts).

In short:

1. Create a `zone-flags.ts` file with:

```
(window as any).__zone_symbol__DISABLE_WRAPPING_UNCAUGHT_PROMISE_REJECTION = true;
```

2. Insert the following in `polyfills.ts` before `import 'zone.js';`:

```
import `./zone-flags`;
```

This might work best if you only throw `Error` objects and not strings.