# Ionic Angular error log differs between Android & iOS ( Cordova ) and cannot build stack trace on Rollbar for iOS

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, rollbar

Is there a reason why console.error(error) (more precisely the error.message value) differs between iOS and Android in Ionic Angular app (cordova) ?

I wrote these lines to get an exception:

```
const a = null;
a.top();
```

then console.error(error) in my ErrorHandler.

The output for Android seems good but output for iOS is not clear enough.
And I think this is the reason why the stack trace is not correctly built on Rollbar.

Example of output:

***Android***
[image]

***iOS***
[image]

Logs differ in terms on the trace, for Android each trace starts with 'at ...' and ends with file name but for iOS all the error goes on one line with 'step@' instead of 'at' and there is no link to go the file.

Anyone has an idea why this is the case.

- Cordova: 10.0.0
- cordova-ios: 6.1.0
- Angular: 8.0.0

**SOLUTION**
The error was thrown from an async method. Thus Angular's ErrorHandler catches error thrown from non awaited async methods and returns the error as a Promise.

Therefore in the handleError() method, add the line below

```
if (error.promise && error.rejection) { error = error.rejection; }
// handle your error
```

Found this solution thanks to:
[Angular custom error handler not getting error type from promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51951471/angular-custom-error-handler-not-getting-error-type-from-promise)

Full answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you assign `null` value to an object and try to access any of it's properties you will get an error, this error's stack trace ***depends actually on the js engine***:

- `Cannot read property of null` in Chrome
- `null is not an object` in Safari

---

**UPDATE:**
The real issue in fact was `why IOS's error wasn't well built on Rollbar`, as it was suggested, I join what OP added in comments:

> the greatest difference is that for Chrome the error is split on each
> line (stack trace) with each line starting with "at .... " with the
> file at the end (e.g main.js) but for iOS the error goes on one line
> with "step@" instead of "at" as if it is minified

Comment: Yes, but the greatest difference is that for Chrome the error is split on each line (stack trace) with each line starting with "at .... " with the file at the end (e.g main.js) but for iOS the error goes on one line with "step@" instead of "at" as if it is minified. I think should add this to the description.

Comment: @D.Ragoo I think the question should be refactored then, since I did not get your real issue. I thought you were asking for why do we have two different stack traces, however your problem is that why it wasn't well built on Rollbar.

Answer (score 0):

The error was thrown from an async method. Thus Angular's ErrorHandler catches error thrown from non awaited async methods and returns the error as a Promise.

```
async foo() {
 const a = null;
 a.top();
}

foo(); // no await
```

[Angular ErrorHandler Doc](https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler)

Therefore in the handleError() method, add the line below

```
   handleError() {
     if (error.promise && error.rejection) { error = error.rejection; }
     // handle your error
   }
```

Found this solution thanks to: [Angular custom error handler not getting error type from promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51951471/angular-custom-error-handler-not-getting-error-type-from-promise)