# How can I extract ALL the information of the JavaScript native exception?

Tags: javascript, exception

Well, as JavaScript is executed in the client-side, I can't control a bunch of environment variables and, at some point, my app will probably throw an exception.

What I want to do is to get this exception and make my app fail gracefully and show the **maximum information as possible** to the end user (my end users are technical ones). Obviously, the error handling can be done through a simple try...catch block.

What is annoying me is: **how can I know what information is stored in a native exception caught by the `catch` block?**

I assume that the native exceptions thrown by the JS engine of the browser are just objects from the `Error` classes, as by running this code:

```js
try {
  a;
} catch (ex) {
  console.log(ex);
  console.log(new ReferenceError("`Custom` error"));
}
```

I get the same structure:

```
ReferenceError: a is not defined
    at http://stacksnippets.net/js:14:3
ReferenceError: `Custom` error
    at http://stacksnippets.net/js:17:15
```

Well, the `console.log` of a normal object is *slightly* different than this, but assuming that the `ex` variable is an object, I could loop through it by a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), right?

Well, no.

This code doesn't show **anything** in the log:

```js
try {
  a;
} catch (ex) {
  for (prop in ex) {
    console.log(prop, ": ", ex[prop]);
  }
}
```

So, my question is:
**How can I get all the information stored in a native JavaScript exception?**

Yes, I know that I could access the properties directly by `ex.name`, `ex.description`, `ex.message`, `ex.stack`, and so on, but I would like to avoid that. Some browser can implement something that another browser don't have, so I will be missing some information when running in the first one (as you can see by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/147891/3136474), the `stack` property, for example, was first implemented by Firefox).

And, if someone can explain, I would like to understand what is the real nature of the JavaScript exceptions (are they objects? why they look so different in the console?) and why can't I loop though it with a for...in block (probably the answers are very related).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to understand what is the real nature of the JavaScript
>   exceptions (are they objects? why they look so different in the
>   console?)

Javascript exceptions are regular javascript objects. You can see the object definition [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)

> and why can't I loop though it with a for...in block (probably the
>   answers are very related).

Iterating over error's properties using `for (prop in ex) {` does not work since the properties are not marked as [enumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893718/what-does-enumerable-mean) (this is also shown in the code snippet below by printing the property descriptior)

You can switch to use [getOwnPropertyNames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) to list all properties.

The code below illustrates how this can be used - not sure if its ok to use `getOwnPropertyNames` & `ex[property]` in this fashion, but it is a possible solution.

```js
function propsToStr(obj) {
  var str = '';
  for (prop in obj) {
    str += prop + "=" + obj[prop] + ",";
  }
  return str;
}

try {
  a;
} catch (ex) {
  console.log(ex);
  var propertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(ex);
  propertyNames.forEach(function(property) {
    var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(ex, property);
    console.log(property + ":" + ex[property] + ":" + propsToStr(descriptor));
  });
}
```